# What's the way to expose a Kubernetes deployment to the world using HTTPS on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, kubernetes

Suppose I have a deployment named `app` running on my Kubernetes cluster (which is running on AWS) which is defined as such:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.6.0 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

(source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment)

I want to expose these pods to world using an AWS ELB. Additionally, it is required (and generally advisable) to serve this service over HTTPS. As a matter of convenience, I would like to leverage AWS's Certificate Manager (ACM) to get free, evergreen certificates, instead of buying and managing the certificates myself.

If I try to expose the pods by creating a service using this command:
`kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --target-port=80 --name=nginx-svc`

An ELB is created, but it is a TCP load balancer, completely unaware of HTTP and I am unable to set an ACM certificate to it.

How can I create the service so Kubernetes will create an HTTP load balancer and set my certificate to it?

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem myself. I don't have an answer yet either, but I'd suggest you look into creating an ingress https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/. An ingress will create a route from the external world into your cluster, and it includes support for your TLS cert.

Comment: Thanks for he reply. I actually figured it out, read below and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though not very well documented it is indeed possible to do this. You can see on GitHub the source code of the module which is responsible for it here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/aws/aws.go#L125

In order to utilize this feature create a YAML nginx-svc.yaml file like so:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-west-1:<account number>:certificate/<certificate id>
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

and use kubectl to create it:
`kubectl create -f nginx-svc.yaml`

wait a few minutes and you'll be good to go!